# Convert complete object to JSON

Tags: java, json

Hi I have a class like this :

```
public class A {
String x;
String y;
String data;
}
```

The variables x and y contain normal Strings but variable data contains a JSON string, i.e, '

```
x = "aaaa";
y = "bbbb";
data = "{\"key\":\"val\"}";
```

I want to convert the complete object in JSON such that final output is :

```
{
x : "aaaa",
y : "bbbb",
data : {
      "key" : "val"
       }
}
```

I tried using `new JSONObject(object)` to convert the object to JSON. It does fine for `x` and `y` attributes but the `data` remains as a String like this :

```
data : "{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}"
```

. I want `data` to be JSONified as well in one go.

How to implement this?

Comment: Your project is a maven or gradle project?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is having your `data` field be another object.

```
public class Data {

   String key;
   String val;
}
```

and in your class;

```
public class A { //Java classes start with uppercase

   String x;
   String y;
   Data data;
}
```

Comment: Understand, but I won't be able to modify the class from which I am obtaining the data field.

Comment: This answer sounds right to me. The original problem is that the class `a` contains a mixture of plain Java data, and data that is already JSON-encoded. If `a` already contains JSON-encoded data, you shouldn't be asking a JSON encoder to encode it again. You'll have to write to logic to do the coding.

Comment: @Maverick you might need to extend the ```JSONObject``` class. Why can't you modify the class? Is it sealed in a .jar?

Comment: I understand and it does really seem to be the most suitable approach. However, this structure is in use by various other dependent packages (not created by me). Changing the type, would lead to additional changes in all the other packages too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the class or create new class extending from it, You can just remove unnecessary characters:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    a obj = new a();
    obj.x = "aaaa";
    obj.y = "bbbb";
    obj.data = "{\"key\":\"val\"}";

    String str = new JSONObject(obj).toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "")
            .replaceAll("\"\\{", "{")
            .replaceAll("\\}\"", "}");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

output:

```
{"data":{"key":"val"},"x":"aaaa","y":"bbbb"}
```

or you can use `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson`  to do the work easily.

Answer (score 0):

Given OP response to Doga Oruc answer here is a workaround: Read your String from member Data and parse that JSON string to `Map<String, Object>` using `JsonObject` class. Then parse your class A to JSON and parse it back to `Map<String, Object>`. In that second map replace key "data" with the value of your first map. This is obviously cumbersome, but that's the price for not being able to modify your original class

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this with Jackson?

```
    class AWrapper {
        String x;
        String y;
        Object data;

        public AWrapper(A a, ObjectMapper mapper) throws IOException {
            this.x = a.x;
            this.y = a.y;
            this.data = mapper.readValue(a.data, Object.class);
        }

        public String getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public String getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public Object getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    class SomeClass {
        public static String toJson(A a) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            AWrapper aWrapper = new AWrapper(a, mapper);
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(aWrapper);
        }
    }
```